# How to best go about interpreting a flags column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, flags

As the title suggests, how am I best to go about interpreting INT value of a flags column to simple text?

I want to have the SQL automatically interpret any given value

between 1 and 1023 (2⁰ <= x < 2¹⁰ )

where thix X number can only be calculated using

(2⁰ or 2¹ or 2² or 2³ or 2⁴ or 2⁵ or 2⁶ or 2⁷ or 2⁸ or 2⁹) and only using any of the given powers of two ONCE.

Comment: You may use the bitwise operations to determine which bit is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to use the '&' bitwise operator.  Something like:

```
(myValue & 1)
(myValue & 2)
(myValue & 4)
(myValue & 8)
(myValue & 16) -- etc
```

The resulting value will either be a 0 or the power of 2 you're testing.  To make things easy, you can always just cast this as a bit, which will make it 1 if it's non-zero.

The slightly longer answer is: I'd suggest turning it into a view.  That way, any time you need to reference the specific columns, you can use the View instead, and not have to put in bit-references and bit-casts into every Proc/Query that uses them.